# Copiar e colar utilizando comandos em Python

Tags: python, testes-automatizados

Preciso saber como realizar uma copia de texto qualquer da tela, simulando a ação do mouse. Para o mouse, estou usando o PyAutoGui, executando as ações. Preciso salvar o conteúdo copiado e armazenar essa informação em uma variável, a fim de uso futuro. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso ?

Comment: Tu já consegue copiar o conteudo? com o PyAutoGui

Comment: Bom dia, Ewerton. Consigo, sim. Já consigo selecionar uma região e copiar, usando o atalho ctrl+c. Falta só " Colar" essa informação em uma variável .

Comment: Beleza, então segue a minha resposta aí..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o `clipboard` em conjunto com o `PyAutoGui`.

Instalação do clipboard: `pip install clipboard`
Pode ser usado assim:

```
import clipboard
import pyautogui

pyautogui.doubleClick(290, 150)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
text = clipboard.paste()
print(text)
```

Comment: Existe uma maneira de limpar o clipboard antes de dar o campando de copiar ?

Comment: Você quer dizer deixar ele sem nada copiado?

Comment: Se for isso, você pode fazer assim `clipboard.copy("")`